# Tensorflow download_and_convert_mnist_m.py No such file or directory: '~/dsn_data/mnist_m/mnist_m_train'

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist

I have a weird error message using the download_and_convert_mnist_m.py script from github https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/domain_adaptation/datasets.

The command I am using from the models/research/ folder is

```
python domain_adaptation/datasets/download_and_convert_mnist_m.py --dataset_dir=~/dsn_data/
```

The error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "domain_adaptation/datasets/download_and_convert_mnist_m.py", line 237, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "domain_adaptation/datasets/download_and_convert_mnist_m.py", line 233, in main
    run(FLAGS.dataset_dir)
  File "domain_adaptation/datasets/download_and_convert_mnist_m.py", line 201, in run
    os.path.join(dataset_dir, 'mnist_m', 'mnist_m_train'))
  File "domain_adaptation/datasets/download_and_convert_mnist_m.py", line 177, in _get_filenames
    for filename in os.listdir(dataset_dir):
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '~/dsn_data/mnist_m/mnist_m_train'
```

I tried several ways:

- without creating the path before and without having the data before
- create the path before and let it empty
- download and unpack data from https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B_tExHiYS-0vR2dNZEU4NGlSSW8 at the specified path as described here https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/domain_adaptation

I use

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Python 2.7
- tensorflow 1.4.1

What else can I do.. looks like an pretty simple error but I have no more ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The correct command is without the equal sign.

```
python domain_adaptation/datasets/download_and_convert_mnist_m.py --dataset_dir=~/dsn_data/
```